# Regex, match characters and doesn't contain more than one _ followed by another _

Tags: regex

I already got the first part with the matching characters, which looks as following: `^[A-Za-z0-9_]{0,}$`
Now I need too check if there is any underscores followed by another underscore. How can I achieve this?

List for explanation:
AAA_A - True
A_AA_A - True
A__AA - False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `_` outside of the character class and use a `*` quantified group:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OQiw58/1). Due to the `*` after the group, the expression will still match empty strings, but the `+` will not let  the whole string be equal to 1 underscore. That also means that `_` can appear at the start of the string (add a `(?!^)` before `_` if you need to disallow this).

If the string can be empty, or can be equal to `_`, you may also use the `^[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_(?!_)[A-Za-z0-9]*)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/43RPVB/4)) regex variation.

**Pattern details**.

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - zero or more alphanumerics
- `(?:` - start of a group matching a sequence of:

  - `_`  - underscore
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - one  or more alphanumerics
- `)*` - end of the group, can occur 0 or more times
- `$` - end of string.

Another approach - using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OQiw58/3). The `(?!.*__)` will fail the match once there are `__` found somewhere ahead after the start of string. To analyze a multiline string, use a DOTALL modifier (in Ruby/Oniguruma, `/m` modifier), and if it is not available (like in JS), use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: The first regex doesn't allow a single underscore (which may or may not be desired). The second regex would allow `A_A__A`.

Comment: Good, `^(?!.*__)[A-Za-z0-9_]*$` will work if the first one is not what is required.

Comment: I also added a variation of the first regex that will deal with a string that is equal to an underscore.